# Microsoft.Bcl.Async Not Supported in Visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous

I using a class library has a function with declaration like this sample below
 `public  async Task<HidReport> ReadReportAsync(int timeout = 0)
    {
        var readReportDelegate = new ReadReportDelegate(ReadReport);
        return await Task<HidReport>.Factory.FromAsync(readReportDelegate.BeginInvoke, readReportDelegate.EndInvoke, timeout, null);
    }`

when i tried to use it in a sliverlight 5 project i got the error below 
"Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier"
while doing some search online i got a NuGet "Microsoft Async 1.0.168" but it's for visual studio 2012 and i'm using a visual studio 2013 any ideas for solving this problem

Comment: Have you tried installing `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`?

Comment: Yes i install it via NuGet  but i founded it for visual studio 2012 only it's installed successfully but without add any new refrences to my solution and visul studio still get me the same error below "Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier"

Comment: How did you find it for Visual Studio 2012 only? That's not possible. Make sure you do use the correct NuGet package from Microsoft.